# How do I write a script to sudo, then cd, set an environment variable and run a program?

Tags: bash, scripting, sudo, zorin

I'm on ZorinOS 16. I recently set up SearXNG, and every time I reboot my computer I have to run a couple of commands to launch it:

```
sudo -H -u searx -i
cd /usr/local/searx/searx-src
export SEARXNG_SETTINGS_PATH="/etc/searxng/settings.yml"
python searx/webapp.py
```

I tried to write a script/bash to run the commands, but I wasn't able to. The two main issues I faced are the fact that there is a `sudo` inside of the bash and the fact that two different users have to execute the actions. As of now the best I could do was create two different bashes, one that changes the user that I run with `sudo bash chuser.sh` and then `bash searx.sh` to execute the three other commands.
The thing that bothers me the most is the fact that I could not find a way to execute the user change without inputting my sudo password: I tried both running the command with

```
echo <password> | sudo -H -u searx -i
```

and to add this line to my /etc/sudoers

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
eugenio ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/eugenio/chuser.sh
```

but it still always prompt for my sudo password no matter what I do.

I surely am doing something wrong, as I am a complete noob, and I'd love any kind of input. I spent the last days browsing forums and youtube videos, but I couldn't figure it out.
Thanks in advance to anyone who'll reply.

Eugenio

Comment: Search the `sudo` command for `cd`. It will tell you what to do.

Comment: Ok thank you, both for formatting my post and the reply

Comment: If you get it working, then add an answer, so that I can upvote it. If not then amend the question to show what you are stuck on (then leave a comment).